# Hexbins by most common attribute

Tags: qgis, hexagon-binning

I am very new to QGIS.

I have read some similar questions on here but none seem to get me to the correct result. I have a bit of experience with Global Mapper but very little with other GIS software or code so this is new territory for me.

I'm looking to create a hexbin map of point data (from a csv), where each hexbin represents the most common attribute (eg NAME, or a unique integer for each name) of the points within it. So within one hex there may be 500 1s, 200 2s, 3 26s, and 1 63. The output I want would be just 1.

Something like this:
[image: Point Data]

To this:
[image: Hexbins]

Except in QGIS.